# How to run .bat files on windows 2016 server on EC2, after python has been configured?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-ec2

I need to kick off a python script on 2016 windows server EC2 instance on AWS.

When I set the task up in 'task scheduler' the script does not run. I have tried setting up a batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off
python C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\script.py %*
pause
```

I get the following error when I double click the batch file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\script.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am running python 3.6 on anaconda in the windows environment in which my script runs fine. I have also downloaded python 3.6 from the python website and confirmed the path variables exist. Also pandas works in anaconda.

batch filename:

```
test.bat
```

Not sure why my libraries not being read in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was too restart anaconda, after adjusting the path variables.